# What kind of expertise is required to install a gas fireplace log?

Tags: gas, fireplace

I already have a gas igniter for my fireplace and want to replace it with a gas log.  While we do that, I'd like to also upgrade to whatever the latest safety features are for gas fireplaces.

First, I imagine this isn't a do-it-yourself job, is it?  Assuming not, what kind of professional would I seek: a plumber?  handyman?  chimney sweep?  fireplace store?

Answer (score 1):

I consider it a DIY project myself.  However, it may be more ambitious than it seems at first.

- Gas line work.
- Brick/masonry drilling/patching
- Electrical wiring for high heat environment
- Control system
- Modification of fireplace and/or gas log
- Possible flue revision
- Several building authority inspections

Whether this should be a DIY is determined by obtaining and understanding the "building authority" requirements and regulations for your location.  Maybe they say that a NFI professional must do the work.  Or maybe they say "all work must be to X standard and inspected by Y".

Comment: I have put together almost entire houses myself.  I don't think any city would let me sign off on a gas conversion - and I have my electrical license in a few cities.  You will need an electrician and you will need the gas line hooked up and OKed by gas company in my region.  The flue, the install, and the masonry work one can do though.

Comment: @dmoore I think you misunderstood my installation. We already have a gas igniter for logs. I just want to connect the line to a gas log.  No electrical igniter here. No masonry needed.

Comment: @glenviewjeff - I understood - was just commenting on the answer which is broader.   You can connect the log.  You need to buy the right tape and connector piece.  It is really that simple.  But if you smell gas, step back, turn gas off, and figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: I have installed full gas systems from heating, range, dryer, water heaters and BBQ. One home house was totally electric prior. All permitted and inspected. Gas both natural and propane is quite easy but there are requirements like venting, shutoff valves. If allowed by your state make sure you know the requirements for the project and use quality materials .+

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.hansenwholesale.com/gas-logs/installers.asp) suggests buyers look for an expert who is certified with the National Fireplace Institute.

> We recommend you look for HVAC professionals, fireplace installers,
>   plumbers and chimney sweeps that may be listed at the NFI.
>
> It is highly recommended that you have your chimney cleaned thoroughly
>   before you install your gas logs. It just so happens that many chimney
>   sweeps are also qualfied to install gas logs and, in most cases, are
>   eager to offer you a great price on the gas log installation if you
>   are also having your chimney swept. So look for a qualified chimney
>   sweep if you want to kill 2 birds with one stone and save some money.